# Get data from another site - 403 Forbidden

Tags: https

I am trying to create a sharepoint hosted app.
That app is hosted on a sharepoint online site.

It is supposed to access data from a sharepoint online list that is on another site collection (but in the same office365 domain).

Everything is working over http.

I found an example on msdn that gets data from odata.org.
When I use this code it works very well :

```
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
    request.set_url(
        "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories"
        );
    request.set_method("GET");

    // We need the response formatted as JSON.
    request.set_headers({ "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" });
    var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

    // Let users know that there is some
    // processing going on.
    document.getElementById("categories").innerHTML =
                "<P>Loading categories...</P>";

    // Set the event handlers and invoke the request.
    context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);


    function successHandler() {
        // Check for status code == 200
        // Some other status codes, such as 302 redirect
        // do not trigger the errorHandler. 
        if (response.get_statusCode() == 200) {
            var categories;
            var output;

            // Load the OData source from the response.
            categories = JSON.parse(response.get_body());

            // Extract the CategoryName and Description
            // from each result in the response.
            // Build the output as a list.
            output = "<UL>";
            for (var i = 0; i < categories.d.results.length; i++) {
                var categoryName;
                var description;
                categoryName = categories.d.results[i].CategoryName;
                description = categories.d.results[i].Description;
                output += "<LI>" + categoryName + ":&nbsp;" +
                    description + "</LI>";
            }
            output += "</UL>";

            document.getElementById("categories").innerHTML = output;
        }
        else {
            var errordesc;

            errordesc = "<P>Status code: " +
                response.get_statusCode() + "<br/>";
            errordesc += response.get_body();
            document.getElementById("categories").innerHTML = errordesc;
        }
    }

    // Event handler for the error event.
    // Render the response body in the placeholder.
    // The body includes the error message.
    function errorHandler() {
        document.getElementById("categories").innerHTML =
            response.get_body();
    }
```

However, if I change the Northwind url and use the url of my site lists (.../_api/web/lists), which is on https, I get a 403 Forbidden error. (I use this url only for testing purposes).

I think it may be a problem with https. I have read blog posts that advice to deactivate https on the sharepoint development server but it is not possible here since it is on sharpoint online. And I want to use https.

I have added the remote endpoint in the appmanifest of course.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access data from different site collection, you need to use `SP.RequestExecutor.js` file.

The sample code is present in the following msdn links:

[Access SharePoint 2013 data from apps using the cross-domain library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Work with the cross-domain library across different Internet Explorer security zones in apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj612823%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I already tried this but I had some problems with security. Then I came across this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895(v=office.15).aspx. I will give RequestExecutor another try. I think my problem had something to do with tenant administrator rights.

Comment: If you are having security issues, I guess second link may help. For cross domain calls in SP, we usually use SP.RequestExecutor.js. Tell me if you face any other issue